# c++ numbering the inputs for simple program

Tags: c++

so im new to c++ and im doing a program that takes user inputs for any amount number say 5 so i will get 5 inputs from user and calculate the sum of it ,i did make the program but what i want for the output is say

"Enter Input 1:xx
"Enter Input 2:xx

so on and on as the user input say 5 so it goes on for 5 times however my program takes the user input  and i enter it, it dosnt say enter input 1  ,so i want to show the enter input 1 enter 2 part hope someone can help me with this sorry for my poor explanation

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (true) {
        // prompts the user to ask how many inputs they want
        int x;

        cout << "Enter input : ";
        cin >> x;

        // If x = -1 dont repeat the loop
        if (x == -1)
            
            break;

        // get the input from above and calculate the total of the input
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            sum += value;
        }

        // Output the total
        cout << "Output total: " << sum << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `int index = 0` before `while` loop and do `cout << "Enter input " << ++index << ": "`

Comment: that does not work as what i intended ,it gives the first line the number 1 where as the inputs are blank

Answer (score 0):

Okay to start out, there are times when to use break and there are times not to. This scenario is not meant for them. Although, I used one in my code I did it because I am rushing. I would recommend to take the code snippet, learn from it, and see how to optimize it :)

Also, just for future purposes its important to understand your task at hand and be able to communicate it well so others can help debug and answer your question.
Heres what I think your question is:
"I want to make a program in cpp that allows the user to first submit how many numbers they would like to input. From there I would then ask them for the indicated number of inputs. After gathering all inputs I will then add those numbers together and output the sum. If at any point they decide to type in -1, I will stop asking for inputs and give their sum on the spot."

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool runProgram = true;
    cout << "Hi welcome to my sum calculator program!\n";
    cout << "This program will prompt you for a number of inputs and then calculate the total of them.\n";
    cout << "If you no longer want to be prompted for numbers at any time type in -1!\n";
    cout << "Press enter to begin!\n";
    cin.get();
    while (runProgram) {
        // prompts the user to ask how many inputs they want
        int x;

        cout << "How many inputs?\n";
        cin >> x;

        // If x = -1 dont repeat the loop
        if (x == -1){
            runProgram = false;
        }else{
                    // get the input from above and calculate the total of the input
        int sum = 0;
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            cout<< "Input #" << i+1;
            cin >> val;
            if(val == -1){
                runProgram = false;
                break;
            }
            sum += val;
        }
        // Output the total
        cout << "Your Output total is " << sum << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes ,you understood my question but not what i wanted to get ,the guy above commented solved my problem but not in the way i wanted so i used your code and modified it to my program but that solved my problem of number input but now it dosnt loop and exit after it gives out the solution, thanks for the help ,ill probably look around

Comment: ```int main() {
 int x;
 do {
  cout << "Enter Inputs:\n";//asks user for input
  cin >> x;

  int sum = 0;
  int value = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
   cout << "Input Value# " << i + 1;
   cin >> value;

   sum += value;
   //output the total 
   cout << "Your output total is " << sum;
  }
 } while (x == -1);
  //exit the program if user enters -1
  cout << "thank you for using this program";
 
 return 0;
} ```ive tried to use do while loop as thats the suggested method but the result is horrible maybe you can show me how to implement it in do while loop ?